# Liquibase ignorable comments

Tags: liquibase

Is there a way we can add comments in liquibase file which are not parsed by the program?

We are using the text format for the changes.sql and this is how it looks

```
--changeset Sapan.Parikh:MyUniqueAlphaNumericId5
--comment: Table created for liquibase testing purpose with non numeric id
--6:10 PM 11/10/2015
create table liqui_test11 (
id int primary key,
name varchar(255)
);
create table liqui_test9 (
id int primary key,
name varchar(255)
);
create table liqui_test10 (
id int primary key,
name varchar(255)
);
```

Our organization has been using similar change log for years and while migrating to Liquibase we want to be able to do two things.

- Add dashes or hashes after each changeset.
- And after every production build we add a comment at the end of the changes file.

For instance

```
--changeset Sapan.Parikh:MyUniqueAlphaNumericId5
--comment: Table created for liquibase testing purpose with non numeric id
--6:10 PM 11/10/2015
create table liqui_test11 (
id int primary key,
name varchar(255)
);
-----------------------------------------------------------------
--changeset Sapan.Parikh:MyUniqueAlphaNumericId4
--comment: Table created for liquibase testing purpose with non numeric id
--6:10 PM 11/10/2015
create table liqui_test12 (
id int primary key,
name varchar(255)
);
###------------------Build 10.0.1 Made-------------------
```

Now if we add just dashes`-` or `#` the luqibase task is breaking and DB upgrade does not happen. Is there a way to accommodate comments which are not parsed by liquibase engine?

Comment: Did you try to use `/* ... */` style comments? `##` isn't a legal comment in SQL, so I would assume that Liquibase chokes on that (but maybe it has a special treatment for that - we exclusively use the XML format)

Comment: Yes, and that does not work as well

Answer (score 0):

You can just persist your comments and strip them right before executing liquibase 
- can be done easily using *sed*

Comment: but the proc gets promoted with stripped comments in the higher env... I need to have the comments when I see it in any env.